# implicit reinterpret cast on reference without warning/error

Tags: c++, c++11, casting, language-lawyer, reinterpret-cast

Just found the reason for an insidious crash to be a **unchecked wild cast** by the compiler, disregarding the types. Is this *intended behaviour* or a compiler bug?

**Problem**: When a type definition is involved, it is possible to make an implicit reinterpret cast, undermining the type system.

```
#include <iostream>

template<class A, class B>
inline bool
isSameObject (A const& a, B const& b)
{
  return static_cast<const void*> (&a)
      == static_cast<const void*> (&b);
}


class Wau
  {
    int i = -1;
  };

class Miau
  {
  public:
    uint u = 1;
  };


int
main (int, char**)
{
  Wau wau;
  using ID = Miau &;
  ID wuff = ID(wau);      // <<---disaster

  std::cout << "Miau=" << wuff.u
            << " ref to same object: " <<std::boolalpha<< isSameObject (wau, wuff)
            << std::endl; 
  return 0;
}
```

I was shocked to find out that gcc-4.9, gcc-6.3 and clang-3.8 accept this code without any error and produce the following output:

```
Miau=4294967295 ref to same object: true
```

Please note I use the type constructor syntax `ID(wau)`. I would expect such behaviour on a C-style cast, i.e. `(ID)wau`. Only when using the new-style curly braces syntax `ID{wau}` we get the expected error...

```
~$ g++ -std=c++11 -o aua woot.cpp

woot.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
woot.cpp:31:21: error: no matching function for call to ‘Miau::Miau(<brace-enclosed initializer list>)’
     ID wuff = ID{wau};
                 ^
woot.cpp:10:7: note: candidate: constexpr Miau::Miau()
 class Miau
       ^~~~
woot.cpp:10:7: note:   candidate expects 0 arguments, 1 provided
woot.cpp:10:7: note: candidate: constexpr Miau::Miau(const Miau&)
woot.cpp:10:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘Wau’ to ‘const Miau&’
woot.cpp:10:7: note: candidate: constexpr Miau::Miau(Miau&&)
woot.cpp:10:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘Wau’ to ‘Miau&&’
```

Unfortunately, the curly-braces syntax is frequently a no-go in template heavy code, due to the `std::initializer_list` fiasco. So for me this is a serious concern, since the protection by the type system effectively breaks down here.

- Can someone explain the reasoning behind this behaviour?
- Is it some kind of backwards compatibility (again, sigh)?

Comment: `ID(wau);` is not a construction, it's a functional-style cast, which is equivalent to a c-style cast like: `(ID)wau;`. It's silly, but required for C backwards compatibility.

Comment: Foo(whatever) is basically the same as (Foo)whatever. Just slightly different syntax.

Comment: C-style casts, function-style cast (a C-style cast variant), reinterpret_cast are all sharp knives.  You are telling the compiler "trust me, I know what I'm doing", even if what you are doing is broken.

Comment: "type constructor syntax" Haha, that's what i'll use next time to comment a dirty cast ;)

Comment: @Frank : oh thanks! I was under the (wrong) assumption there would be a difference.

Comment: @NathanOliver thanks for the tip!

Comment: @Frank It’s absolutely *not* needed for C backwards compatibility. C has no function-style cast. It was always a mistake in C++ but is now needed for backwards compatibility with previous versions of C++.

Comment: @NathanOliver unfortunately it's not the same. Checked it just now, using `std::addressof(a)` still needs the cast, because both are pointers to different types. `addressof` only deals with the possibility of an overloaded `&` operator (oh my!)

Comment: @Ichthyo I'm sorry.  I though they were the same type.  Somehow I missed the `A` and `B`.

Comment: That syntax construct predates the first C++ standard, even the first C++ standard draft. It's very old. Now it's part of the burden of the inane past choices.

Comment: `T(arg)` where `T` is a class type is certainly not going away ... I don't see the need to allow this for `T` being typedef of a reference type though

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To go full language-lawyer, `T(expression)` is a *conversion* of the result of `expression` to `T`<sup>1</sup>. This conversion has as effect to call the class' constructor<sup>2</sup>. This is why we tend to call a non-explicit constructor taking exactly one argument a *conversion constructor*.

```
using ID = Miau &;
ID wuff = ID(wau);
```

This is then equivalent to a *cast expression* to `ID`. Since `ID` is not a class type, a C-style cast occurs.

> Can someone explain the reasoning behind this behaviour?

I really can't tell why is was ever part of C++. This is not needed. And it is harmful.

> Is it some kind of backwards compatibility (again, sigh)?

Not necessarily, with C++11 to C++20 we've seen breaking changes. This could be removed some day, but I doubt it would.

---

<sup>1)</sup>

> #### [`[expr.type.conv]`](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.post#expr.type.conv)
>
> 1. A *simple-type-specifier* or *typename-specifier* followed by a parenthesized optional *expression-list* or by a *braced-init-list* (the initializer) constructs a value of the specified type given the initializer. [...]
> 2. If the initializer is a parenthesized single expression, the **type conversion expression is equivalent to the corresponding cast expression**. [...]

<sup>2)</sup> (when `T` is of class type and such a constructor exists)

> #### [`[class.ctor]/2`](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.ctor#2)
>
> A constructor is used to initialize objects of its class type. Because constructors do not have names, they are never found during name lookup; however an explicit type conversion using the functional notation ([expr.type.conv]) will cause a constructor to be called to initialize an object.

Comment: Thanks for going 'language lawyer'. This was exactly the kind of clarification I needed. Seems like the actual pitfall I was trapped by is that a reference is not a class type...

Comment: Your first quote says "constructs a value of the specified type" but there cannot be a value of reference type. I'm dubious about whether the standard intended to allow this code

Answer (score 4):

> it is possible to make an implicit reinterpret cast, undermining the type system.
>
> ```
> ID wuff = ID(wau);
> ```

That's not an "implicit" reinterpret cast. That is an *explicit* type conversion. Although, the fact that the conversion does reinterpretation is indeed not easy to see. Specifically, the syntax of the cast is called "functional style".

If you're unsure what type of cast an explicit type conversion (whether using the functional syntax, or the C style syntax) performs, then you should refrain from using it. Many would argue that explicit type conversions should never be used.

If you had used `static_cast` instead, you would have stayed within the protection of the type system:

```
ID wuff = static_cast<ID>(wau);

error: non-const lvalue reference to type 'Miau' cannot bind to a value of unrelated type 'Wau'
```

It's often also safe to simply rely on implicit conversions:

```
ID wuff = wau;

error: non-const lvalue reference to type 'Miau' cannot bind to a value of unrelated type 'Wau'
```

> Is this intended behaviour

Yes.

> or a compiler bug?

No.

Comment: Agreed to your points, however often you deliberately want the explicit conversions, and '`static_cast`' does not well express that intention IMHO. An explicit conversion can do a lot of runtime work. In my actual case, what is called `Miau` in my example was indeed an special ID type, and the conversion consulted a lookup-table.

Comment: As the answer by @ysc highlights, the _actual trap I went into_ was the fact that the type definition involved a reference, which is not a class type.

Comment: @Ichthyo Technically speaking, I see no difference. A functional cast does always the same as an equivalent C style cast (if an equivalent cast exists). A C-style cast of a class type would be same as a functional cast. But indeed: It's not safe to use a functional (or C style) cast unless you know exactly what kind of type you're dealing with.

Comment: not always, see 7.6.1.3 in the reference ysc linked. If the functional-notation-style cast uses curly braces, it goes though the corresponding object conversion ctor, even when the type ID is a const reference to that object, as it was in my (actual) use case. If however the argument is in parentheses, it does a C-style cast. This is what I've learned today

Comment: @Ichthyo Oh, I had't realized that the new braced-init syntax is also called *functional* notation. Indeed, my previous comment applies to the old non-curly brace version only.